# Error when trying to Find a record in a simple table with Linq to Entities

Tags: c#, linq

I have a simple table "Orders" that has several records in it. I am using the code

```
  Order order;
        if (reg.OrderId != null)
        {
            order = db.Orders.Find(reg.OrderId);
        }
        else
        {
            order = new Order();
        }
```

to get an existing order from my table. reg.OrderId evaluates to a simple integer (i.e. 55).

When stepping thru the code I get an error: **"This expression causes side effects and will not be evaluated"**

But if I make the same call in LinqPad against the same context it returns the data as expected. This seems like a very simple piece of code.

Why am I getting the error? And/or how do I troubleshoot this further since it works in LinqPad?

Comment: I dont have an answer, but I've seen similar things when I've been debugging for a while.  [Turning it off and back on again](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nn2FB1P_Mn8) will sometimes give me different results.

Comment: `John S` take a look at this [MSDN Entity Framework Querying/Finding Entities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj573936.aspx)

Comment: What kind of "Error" are you getting?  I believe that message should only appear in the Watch window (Because you don't want to be doing something like a Find() on every step).  The code itself should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why you are getting the error but here is a suggestion:

```
Order order;
if(order == null)
{
    if (reg.OrderId != null)
    {
        order = db.Orders.Where(o => o.OrderId == reg.OrderId).FirstOrDefault();
    }
    else
    {
        order = new Order();
    }
}
```